# when a patent is filed with an IDS form, what does "Information Disclosure Statement considered" mean?

Tags: prior-art, filing, prosecution

Is Anyone  familiar with this under the "Transaction description" tab? And if so, does this mean the application just started being examined by the examiner? how long after this will the examiner reject or allow the claims?